# Cassandra consistency model performance evaluation

Tags: performance-testing, cassandra-2.0

Hi I am a student and am trying to evaluate the latency(Insert, read and Upsert) of cassandra for different consistency models and for different replication factors.

I am using Virtual box on my host system and have 10 ubuntu VMs to form a cluster.
When I run the tests,  sometimes the average latency comes out lesser for a stronger consistency model. 
Also the latency does not increase as I increase the replication factor in some cases which is also not an expected result.

I wanted to know what all could be the possible reasons for such behavior?

Comment: You should tell more about your tests. What kind of test are you running? Does VMs share I/O resources?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things:

- Performance benchmarks using virtual box on a single system will give you very different resutls from a live cluster. For instance, network latencies would be considerably reduced. A real cluster would have different resources available whereas vbox instances are sharing the same resources. Even on a cloud platform, you'd see different numbers.
- When a write request comes in, the coordinator sends to all required replicas a write request in parallel. They all process the write and respond. If your lower consistency write went to a busy node, and the higher consistency write went to enough "faster / available" nodes to make a quorum, then the latter will have lower latency. Also, increasing the replication factor means the data is available in more nodes. So reads can be faster (depending on consistency levels).